# how to get worst case for fibonacci heaps

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

What sequence of operations would give the worst case for fibonacci heaps? Where each node has only one child except for the last node?

For example:

```
5
|
6
|
7
|
8
```

Comment: This is actually the *best* case for a heap.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is actually the best case (as you can see, extract-min is always easy, since we have the element ordered). You should get it by inserting a sequence of reverse-sorted elements (that is, the minimal element would come last) in this manner:

1. insert two elements
2. extract-min
3. repeat

Comment: I think this produces a single tree but it's not as requested (each node should have only one child). Check out here:
http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~aaw/Jason/FibonacciHeapAnimation.html

Answer (score 2):

I think jpalecek's answer doesn't produce the requested tree. Try it here:

http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~aaw/Jason/FibonacciHeapAnimation.html

Also, You can achieve the same result just by inserting whatever number of elements and then extract-min once. Anyway, that's not the request.

To achieve the form you wanted do this:

- insert whatever number of elements - say 1 through 10.
- extract min (now you have a single tree)
- decrease all children to `-inf` except the leftmost, starting from the deepest, and from left to right (see demonstration below).
- after each decrease, delete the min
- repeat step 3

*example:*

- insert 1 through 10:

[image: start]

- extract min:

[image: extractMin]

- decrease `7` to `0`:

[image: firstDec]

- extract min:

[image: extractMin]

- decrease `5` to `0`, extract min , decrease `4` to `0`, extract min , decrease `3` to `0`, extract min , decrease `10` to `0`, extract min:

[image: fin]

**edit:**

I forgot there's a `delete` operation that makes `decrease` then `extract min`, so you can use it instead of the **decrease then extract min** i was doing above.

And note that now when you have a "single path" tree, you can easily keep enlarging it by this sequence of O(1) operations:

- insert 3 elements smaller than the min
- extract min
- delete the new right child

*demonstration (continuing last step from the example):*

- insert `1`,`0`,`-1`:

[image: insert_3_elements]

- extract min:

[image: extractMin2]

- delete new right child (`1`):

[image: deeper]

*all images are created by [this website](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~aaw/Jason/FibonacciHeapAnimation.html)*